# API to get UnreadMessages of an user in an application using moodle

Tags: java, android, moodle, postman

I am looking for an API which would return me a list of the unread messages of a particular user. I would be passing the userId and a status of message.

The message would have a status like: read or unread

Comment: What API? A Moodle API?

Comment: Yes a Moodle Rest API, as my application is written in Java, however Moodle is in PHP. I have checked all of Moodle's Core Rest APIs and none of them have a "status" attribute which is what I need.